# How do I access UIImageViews that have gone outof scope and that shares the same name as multiple others

Tags: iphone, scope, uiimageview

I have a for loop that creates multiple `UIImageViews` that I add to `self.view` I do this in my custom init method.

```
- (id)init {
 if ( self = [super init] ) {
    for ( int i = o; i < [count]; i++ ) {    //count is a variable I am using (typicly 3)
        UIImageView *tmpImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage[data getImage]];
        tmpImagView.tag = i;
        tmpImageView.frame = self.view.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:tmpImageView];
    }
}
```

In my on method I want to access this `tmpImageView` and change it's properties like transform and frame

```
- (void)otherMethod {
    //Play with the tmpImageView's properties
}
```

But the `tmpImageView` is out of scope. How do I access it. `Without using an NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)otherMethod {
    UIImageView* tImageView = (UIImageView*) [self.view viewWithTag: someTag];
    //Play with the tmpImageView's properties
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much I just didn't understand how to use `viewWithTag:` Thanks

Comment: Is that view still in memory even before I were to implement this?

Comment: yes, UIView retains its subviews so you don't need to have extra storage for them